# Electrical circuit with 3 voltage sources and a current dependent voltage source

Tags: circuit-analysis, current-source

I have this exercise where I need to say if the circuit is possible to be connected.
I'm in doubt cause we can't connect different voltage sources in parallel, but this current dependent voltage source and the current source is bugging me. Then, if this circuit is possible, i need to find the electrical power in the current source.

[image]

If you guys can help i appreciate it.

Comment: True 0 Ohm sources or caps or batteries cannot be connected in parallel with different voltages due to the excessive current limits but "current  sources" are ideal high-impedance , which allows that to happen/

Comment: Thank you, so the lateral voltage sources are in series with the 80V source, right? cause the current source act like a resistor.

Comment: No these are ideal current sources and amplifiers with infinite impedance, but real ones like PV sources do act like a negative resistance at MPT Zmpt=Vol/Isc but not for all current as a photo sensitive solar powered photo voltaic current source. transistor CE amps are more ideal inverting current sinks but have a leakage resistance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The analysis of this circuit is pretty straightforward, since you directly know what iΔ is (-25A). Then you can see what the dependent voltage source is (-150V), and you can see that the polarity is flipped, so the voltage on the left adds up to 200V, which is the same as the voltage on the right, so this circuit can exist.

Then you should be able to figure out what the power in the current source is (hint: P=I*something, and Kirchhoff's voltage law)

Comment: Thank you, I really could understand now, but the 80V source, is there any problem with it? sorry if is a newbie question, I'm just in the beginning of the course.

Comment: no, there is no problem with it - you use it to answer the question

Comment: Thanks mate, i appreciate it.